# How to train your brain for work that requires heavier attention to detail

Tags: software-development, professional-development

For the last 5-10 years or so I've worked as a Software Developer in places where design was a bit "ad-hoc" that is requirements were farily vague, open and somewhat flexible as long as basic requirements were delivered. I did pretty well in these conditions as I usually had enough to go by to get the job done in these requirements.

Right now though I'm in a position with very strict requirements on just about all the software being developed there.  One place I'm having trouble is meeting the exacting requirements down to the slightest column widths, font sizes, etc.  Other than this one problem I think I'm doing well, but it's driving some of my peers including the QA teams crazy.

Have other developers faced these issues?  What kinds of things did you do to "train your brain" to better look at these things?

Comment: How long a list are the requirements you have troubles with? Can you make a checklist for yourself that you go through every time you are going to submit to QA?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about psychology / productivity.

Comment: @tekiegreg If this question does get closed (it's borderline IMO), you might try at [productivity.se] instead.

Comment: Yeah I'm kind of wavering on whether or not I want to voluntarily close....if the sentiment continues to head south then I'll take it over there, thanks!

Comment: Hedge your bets and ask there in the meantime to see if you can see a resolution there. If so, link this question to that.

Comment: @FrankFYC [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: @Dukeling I didn't know that. Scratch my idea then.

Comment: @tekiegreg If you want to ask it there, you can flag the question for mod attention and request they migrate it.

Comment: On my Mac, I use the Snappy app. It allows me to take a clipped rectangular screenshot of what I am looking at. And it immediately puts that clipped screen above all my other windows even if I click on a window below it. This allows me to see the important part even if I am back in my IDE coding inside the layout editor/designer. That tool has been invaluable to me. And the free version has more than enough features for my needs. On Linux, you should be able to find a similar tool. On Windows, I have no idea if there is such a tool. http://snappy-app.com/

Comment: And if that's not enough, another thing that you might need is actual test devices and actual monitors that are identical to the ones used by your QA team. I suppose we could give you better advice, but I think, you should ask this question on a technically-related stackexchange. Furthermore, you should tell them what kind of software you're working on.  For instance, expecting pixel-perfect prototypes may be common in iOS, but it is certainly not on Android. On Android, only ranges can be given as requirements, not exact measurements, unless the same phone can be mandated for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Project requirements can be very different between various projects. Sometimes like this you have designers who are very precise, and that doesn't necessarily mean its a problem.

Where it becomes a problem is with the current framework and how the requested adjustments affect the overall project scope and timeline. Make sure that you inform the Project Manager that the framework you are using doesn't make it easy to make these adjustments and that they will need to budget more time for these tasks.

All you need to do is pass on the information that the Task XX3 is going to take longer than the estimated 2 hours; and explain why.

Its not your place to debate the purpose or use of these features... that is what the Project Manager is there for. Let the PM take it to the designers and owners of the project. But it may also be just as out of his control as it is yours, and at the end of the day you are going to have to do the tasks regardless of how difficult or how much time it takes.

I realize that so far I haven't done a good job in answering your question of how to train your brain.

1. Before you start, make a checklist of all items
2. Check for loosely defined or inconsistent requirements and ask for clarification
3. Communicate any design issues... often designers do not think about "State X" or "Case B" until you bring it up... and sometimes that requires rethinking the design
4. Before you commit/submit for review, you should review the requirements and checklist
5. Make sure you have the right tools (Photoshop required to check pixel perfect alignment?)

It seems like you are in early in the project and that it is the first time that you worked with this designer. It will not take long to start to learn what they are looking for and where they are explicit or general.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that has helped me greatly with this is using [test driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).
Writing the tests to the exact specifications required is basically a translation job - you do this before you do actual development.

Putting in tests for more basic requirements allows you to get the satisfaction of getting a win in the early stages every once in a while.

This provides not only motivation and has helped me to ensure my design ideas fit the requirements - because I can quickly tell if what I've come up with runs into issues when considering the final use case - it also ensures you will meet the *exact* requirements once all tests are passing.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to formatting code, most IDEs offer a magic key sequence or menu option that will auto-format your code according to whatever standard you set up.  If you're not using an IDE, then use a standalone program to do it.

For documents, use the standard company templates and don't fiddle with the settings.